# Cómo mostrar las características de un objeto al cambiar de nombre de objeto boolean en java

Tags: java, booleano

Hola estoy aprendiendo a programar en java, y cree una clase llamada Perro, con sus atributos y métodos. También creer un programa principal que pueda crear 4 objetos de tipo Perro y que llame a métodos. En pantalla imprime sus atributos y sus métodos de cada objeto. Pero mi tarea es que mi programa pueda imprimir nuevamente las nuevas características del objeto después de cambiar el nombre del Perro. Cómo puedo hacerlo??

```
public class Perro {
String nombre;
String raza;
String tamano;

public Perro (String nombre, String raza, String tamano){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.raza = raza;
    this.tamano = tamano;
}
public void caminar() {
    System.out.println(nombre + " camina");
}
public void saltar() {
    System.out.println(nombre + " salta");
}
public void correr(){
    System.out.println(nombre + " corre");
}
public void ladrar() {
    System.out.println(nombre + " ladra");
}
```

}

y mi programa principal es

```
public class progprincp {
public static void main (String [] args){
    Perro p1;
    p1 = new Perro("Vovi", "Chusco", "Enorme");
    System.out.println(p1.nombre);
    System.out.println(p1.raza);
    System.out.println(p1.tamano);
    p1.caminar();
    p1.saltar();
    p1.correr();
    p1.ladrar();

    Perro p2;
    p2 = new Perro("Ted", "Chusco", "pequeño");
    System.out.println(p2.nombre);
    System.out.println(p2.raza);
    System.out.println(p2.tamano);
    p2.caminar();
    p2.saltar();
    p2.correr();
    p2.ladrar();

    Perro p3;
    p3 = new Perro("3.14kxu", "pokemon electrico", "medianito");
    System.out.println(p3.nombre);
    System.out.println(p3.raza);
    System.out.println(p3.tamano);
    p3.caminar();
    p3.saltar();
    p3.correr();
    p3.ladrar();

    Perro p4;
    p4 = new Perro("Betún", "Boxer", "Gordito");
    System.out.println(p4.nombre);
    System.out.println(p4.raza);
    System.out.println(p4.tamano);
    p4.caminar();
    p4.saltar();
    p4.correr();
    p4.ladrar();
```

}

Comment: Hola Diego, me gustaría que pusieras el código para ver que es lo que falta, saludos!

Comment: Como bien dice Chris Vazquez pon el codigo que tienes asi te podemos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Gracias @ChrisVazquez  . Ya puse mi codigo

Comment: @brunoDiazmartin ya edite y puse mi codigo, ojala puedan ayudame, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder cambiar el nombre lo ideal es crear las funciones get y set en sus respectivos atributos, estas funciones se pueden crear automáticamente en algunos IDE, por ejemplo yo uso NetBeans y se crean Alt+Insert y selecciono getter and setter y los crea en automático.

```
public class Perro {

    String nombre;
    String raza;
    String tamano;

    public Perro(String nombre, String raza, String tamano) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.raza = raza;
        this.tamano = tamano;
    }

    public void caminar() {
        System.out.println(nombre + " camina");
    }

    public void saltar() {
        System.out.println(nombre + " salta");
    }

    public void correr() {
        System.out.println(nombre + " corre");
    }

    public void ladrar() {
        System.out.println(nombre + " ladra");
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getRaza() {
        return raza;
    }

    public void setRaza(String raza) {
        this.raza = raza;
    }

    public String getTamano() {
        return tamano;
    }

    public void setTamano(String tamano) {
        this.tamano = tamano;
    }
```

Así quedaría la clase perro, no hace falta crear todas las funciones si no las vas a usar.
La clase principal quedaría así

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Perro p1 = new Perro("Zenit", "Beagle", "Mediano");
        System.out.println(p1.getNombre() + "\n" + p1.getRaza() + "\n" + p1.getTamano());
        p1.caminar();
        p1.saltar();
        p1.correr();
        p1.ladrar();

        p1.setNombre("NuevoNombre");//Esta función es la que cambia el nombre
        System.out.println(p1.getNombre() + "\n" + p1.getRaza() + "\n" + p1.getTamano());
        p1.caminar();
        p1.saltar();
        p1.correr();
        p1.ladrar();
    }
```

La función setNombre es la que se encarga de ponerle un nuevo nombre, ya solo imprimes de todo de nuevo.
Espero esto te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: Gracias amigo, voy a revisar el código, aunque hay algunas cosas que aun no he visto, pero me recomendarías algún libro o separata para aprender a programar en java, aparte de el material que ya me dan para mis clases.

Comment: Puedes encontrar "Como Programar en Java - Deitel" ese a mí me gustó.